# align a tags from top to bottom

Tags: css

I am trying to customize a free widget, but I dont have access to edit the html. I am only given access to the css. I want to be able to align the `a` tags virtually. I have tried the following css, but the tags are right on top of each other/ How do I put space between them?

HTML

```
<span><a href="#" title="Delete">[×]</a>&nbsp;<a href="#" title="Ban">[o]</a>&nbsp;</span>
```

CSS

span a { position:fixed; }

JSFIddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gfvAw/58/

Comment: `fixed` takes the elements out of the document flow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning - I don't think that is what you were after...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always float and clear the anchor tags:

```
a { float: left; clear: left; }
```

Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/gfvAw/60/

Answer (score 0):

`a { display: block; }`

This will convert the `a` tags into `block` elements, meaning they will automatically expand to fit their containers.

However, you should realize that using `block` elements means the user will be able to click anywhere in the block, rather than just on top of the link text. A solution to that problem would be to use jQuery to insert `<br/>` tags after each `a` tag. Or you could replace the `&nbsp;` entities with `<br/>` tags, as well.